# how to select the last 8 row and Sum other column in Database SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am newbie. Please help me with this problem.
I want to select the last 8 row and other column from database.
I have column week, date, and value1.
I want to sum value1 group by week and only display the last 8 records. I can display the last 8 week  but can't sum the value1.
Here is my code to display the week :

```
SELECT week FROM 
(SELECT Top 7 week 
 FROM tbData 
 Group By week 
 ORDER BY week DESC) as LW 
ORDER BY week ASC
```

It give me the last 8 week, then I change it into this to display sum(value1) :

```
SELECT SUM(Value1) as TValue1, week 
FROM 
(SELECT Top 7 week 
 FROM tbData 
 Group By week 
 ORDER BY week DESC) as LW 
ORDER BY week ASC"
```

but it give me error Invalid column name 'Value1'.

what should I do to get it right... 
Thanks in advances....

Comment: If `TOP x` then `SQL Server`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Value1` column in your subquery. I expect you wanted to do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Value1) as TValue1, week 
FROM 
(SELECT Top 7 week, sum(Value1) as Value1
 FROM tbData 
 Group By week 
 ORDER BY week DESC) as LW 
ORDER BY week ASC
```

Comment: Dear Dean,,,
I tried your code,, but it give me the error invalid Column name Value1... but there is a column name Value1 in my table...
Thank you for helping me solving my problem...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT SUM(Value1) as TValue1, week 
    FROM 
    (SELECT Top 7 week , sum(Value1) Value1
     FROM tbData 
     Group By week 
     ORDER BY week DESC) as LW 
    ORDER BY week ASC
```

and drop this at the end: > " <

**EDIT:**

try the subquery alone:

```
SELECT Top 7 
 week
 ,sum(Value1) Value1
FROM 
 tbData 
GROUP BY 
 week 
ORDER BY 
 week DESC
```

copy paste it into your query editor.

if you get an error "invalid columname" it is most likely, the column "Value1" doesn't exist. Make sure it is spelled correctly and you are not trying to use an alias.

Comment: Dear Der U,,,
I tried your code,, but it give me the error invalid Column name Value1... but there is a column name Value1 in my table...
Thank you for helping me solving my problem...